# How can I locate stats on my bounty questions?

Tags: support, bounty

Is there a feature (or a database query) that would help me locate all questions that I have placed on bounty for both my own questions as well as other people's questions? I'd also like to get to get some statistics with it, if possible, such as:

- All (or most recent) date(s) the bounty was placed (regardless of who did it)
- How often it was placed on bounty (regardless of who did it)
- Whether I awarded the bounty or it was auto-rewarded (maybe there is already an indicator for this?) - my own questions or others'

Comment: In your user profile https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/5275/danf?tab=bounties there's a list of offered bounties and earned bounties (so too on everyone else's respective profiles)